# Integration of Excel File Viewer or Editor?

Tags: users

I'm looking for a solution of my problem and I'm not sure if mine is the best put it will do the job for now.
I want the have a basic page with embed excel file iframe from google docs after user login.I have done that and it works fine but the problem comes when I have for example 50 users and each has to see his file.How can I deliver exact file for the user?
Here is an example: User 1 logs in and a menu button shows after log in, he presses it and the basic page with his embed excel sheet shows up...thats all

iframe contains the link like this:

```
<iframe src="docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…; width="600" height="400"</iframe>
```

If we have 50 users we will have 50 different links (Google generates different links to different files from Google Drive and we will know them already), each link for user will be the same over the time and it will not change , so we don't need to calculate anything, yeah...and each user will have his link in his iframe loaded as soon as he logs in to his account.

I'm still not good enough at codding so an example would be appreciated.

Comment: You should explain in detail how you have solved it and someone may be able to point you in the right direction to extend to solution to N users.

Comment: by solution I ment the logic, not the code

Comment: Thi thing is first we don't how to link to the Sheet file, just a link? it's ok to have a link per user? Is the same link alwasy for each user? Does it change? That link can be calculated for every new user? Does thad min should have to set each link for each user? And those question only if you use just a link. Your question is too broad, IMHO.

Comment: iframe contains the link:

    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dNgAGWKVcGkZQh6iCzVeviC6C-aLT4R4R49Zz3vnOVg/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="600" height="400"</iframe>
If we have 50 users we will have 50 different links(google generates different links to different files from google drive and we will know them already), each link for user will be the same over the time and it will not change , so we don't need to calculate anything, yeah...and each user will have his link in his iframe loaded as soon as he logs in to his account.

Comment: it's better if you actually edit your question, not add a comment. The information is useful and a new reader should get on the first time, not digging in the answer comments. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: What Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Iframe module](https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe) (available for Drupal 7 and 8).

> A custom field, which lets you add a complete iframe to your content
>   types; including Src-URL, setting width and height, optionally a title
>   above, and optionally a target attribute.

Add an iframe field on each user profile  with their Google Docs URL. Depending on who is reponsible of adding he field to the user profile (admin or the user itself) you adjust permissions.

Then use that field to render it.